# XmlValueDisconnectedException when getting row index (getRowNum())

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi, row

In my code I am going through an XLSX-file row by row, validating them against a database with Apache POI 4.1.0. If I find a incorrect row I will "mark" them for deletion by adding it to the the `List<XSSFRow> toRemove`. After iterating over every row this small method is supposed to remove the rows marked for deletion:

```
ListIterator<XSSFRow> rowIterator = toRemove.listIterator(toRemove.size());

while (rowIterator.hasPrevious()) {
    XSSFRow row = rowIterator.previous();
    if (row != null && row.getSheet() == sheet) {
        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        int rowIndex = row.getRowNum();

        if (rowIndex == lastRowNum) {
            sheet.removeRow(row);
        } else if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum) {
            sheet.removeRow(row);

        } else {
            System.out.println("\u001B[31mERROR: Removal failed because row " + rowIndex + " is out of bounds\u001B[0m");
        }
        System.out.println("Row " + rowIndex + " successfully removed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Row skipped in removal because it was null already");
    }
}
```

But for some unknown reason it removes all rows perfectly and then throws a XmlValueDisconnectedException when getting the row index (`getRowNum()`) of the last (first added) row.

Relevant part of the Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_orphaned(XmlObjectBase.java:1258)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRowImpl.getR(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getRowNum(XSSFRow.java:400)
    at Overview.removeRows(Overview.java:122)
```

EDIT: I also tried changing the iteration process (see below) but the error stays the same.

```
for (XSSFRow row : toRemove) {
   // same code as above without iterator and while
}
```

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if not the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: The error occurs if one row is double contained in `List` `toRemove`. Since the list iterator iterates backwards, the last occurrence of the row will be successfully removed. But then if the same row occurs again later, the `row.getRowNum()` fails that way because the row does not more exists in the sheet.

Comment: Now you check whether the `Row` object you have is related to the `Sheet` object you have. That can be true even if that row already is removed from the sheet. The removing removes the row from the sheets storage. But this does not update all related objects already stored somewhere in memory. You need avoid that same rows are double contained in your `List<XSSFRow>` `toRemove`. I would not collecting the rows to remove in a  `List<XSSFRow>` but the row numbers to remove in a `Set<Integer>`. That would avoid duplicates. The row to remove then can simply got via `sheet.getRow(rowNumber)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs if one row is double contained in List `toRemove`. A `List` allows duplicate entries. So the same row may be double added to the `List`. If then `Iterator` gets the first occurrence of that row and this will be removed properly from the sheet. But then if the same row occurs again later, the `row.getRowNum()` fails that way because the row does not more exists in the sheet.

Here is complete code to reproduce that behavior:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.*;

public class ExcelRemoveRows {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String filePath = "Excel.xlsx"; // must contain at least 5 filled rows

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  List<Row> toRemoveList = new ArrayList<Row>();
  toRemoveList.add(sheet.getRow(0));
  toRemoveList.add(sheet.getRow(2));
  toRemoveList.add(sheet.getRow(4));
  toRemoveList.add(sheet.getRow(2)); // this produces the error

  System.out.println(toRemoveList); // contains row hawing index 2 (r="3") two times

  for (Row row : toRemoveList) {
   System.out.println(row.getRowNum()); // XmlValueDisconnectedException on second occurance of row index 2
   sheet.removeRow(row);
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Changed"+filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

The solution is to avoid that the `List` contains the same row multiple times.

I would not collecting the rows to remove in a `List<XSSFRow>` but the row numbers to remove in a `Set<Integer>`. That would avoid duplicates since a `Set` does not allow duplicate elements. The row to remove then can simply got via `sheet.getRow(rowNum)`.

Code:

```
...
  Set<Integer> toRemoveSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
  toRemoveSet.add(sheet.getRow(0).getRowNum());
  toRemoveSet.add(sheet.getRow(2).getRowNum());
  toRemoveSet.add(sheet.getRow(4).getRowNum());
  toRemoveSet.add(sheet.getRow(2).getRowNum());

  System.out.println(toRemoveSet); // does not contain the row index 2 two times

  for (Integer rowNum : toRemoveSet) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
   System.out.println(row.getRowNum());
   sheet.removeRow(row);
  }
...
```